# Joomla - How to let Registered users change their password

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a website based on Joomla 1.5.22. I want users to change the password on the frontend. Using the menumanager i can bring up the page but i want to show only username, email, password and verify password. But it's bringing more info like change backend language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the User Form menu item you mentioned, as that is the native interface for allowing users to change their password. However, since you want to avoid the other fields, you can simply disable "Front end user parameters" in Global Configuration > System.

Comment: In Joomla 2.5 it's in Users->User Manager, then click the "Options" icon near the top right of the page

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-let-users-manage-their-own-accounts-in-joom.html

Concretely, the URL for the user to edit her details is here:

```
index.php?option=com_user&view=user&layout=form
```

Joomla 1.5